# How to concat a number of arrays as a single array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How to concat a number of arrays as a single array in C#?

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Exp2
{
    class Program2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program2 pgm = new Program2();
            Console.Write("Enter number of Arrays do you want : ");
            int numberOfArrays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] narray = new int[numberOfArrays];
            int[] el=new int[100];
            int[] el1 = new int[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < narray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number of Elements do you want in Array {0}: ",i+1);
                int ai = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int j = 0; j < ai; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the {1} Elements do you want in Array {0}: ", i+1,j+1);
                    el[j]= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                el1 =el1.Concat(el).ToArray();
            }
            foreach (int val in el1)
            {
                Console.Write(val+" ");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Enter number of Arrays do you want : 3
Enter number of Elements do you want in Array 1: 3
Enter the 1 Elements do you want in Array 1: 5
Enter the 2 Elements do you want in Array 1: 6
Enter the 3 Elements do you want in Array 1: 9
Enter number of Elements do you want in Array 2: 4
Enter the 1 Elements do you want in Array 2: 5
Enter the 2 Elements do you want in Array 2: 8
Enter the 3 Elements do you want in Array 2: 2
Enter the 4 Elements do you want in Array 2: 2
Enter number of Elements do you want in Array 3: 5
Enter the 1 Elements do you want in Array 3: 32
Enter the 2 Elements do you want in Array 3: 4
Enter the 3 Elements do you want in Array 3: 6
Enter the 4 Elements do you want in Array 3: 6
Enter the 5 Elements do you want in Array 3: 4
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 8 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 4 6 6 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I display only the input of user?

Comment: Essentially you have only one Int array and not multiple array

Comment: You can use `List<int>` instead of `int[]` and create/fill them dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the number of elements, you can use List rather than array.

Concat is easy in list.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
// Do your action to assign elements in list1 and list2

// To add list1 into list2
list2.AddRange(list1);
```

Comment: but using this solution you cannot differentiate between the sublist elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and a List :

The dictionary maps the list to its number.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Arrays do you want : ");

int numberOfArrays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int k = 1; k < numberOfArrays; k++)
{
    var currentArray = dict[k] = new List<int>();

    Console.WriteLine($"Enter array {k} Length:");

    int arrayLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Enter the {j}-th Element you want in Array {k}: ");
       currentArray.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }

}

foreach(var pair in dict)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}-th array elements : ");

     foreach(var element in pair.Value)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "foreach" loop use "for" loop like this .

```
for (int i= 0;i< el1.Length;i++)
{   
   if (el1[i] != 0)
   Console.Write(el1[i] + " ");
   else continue;
}
```

**warning:** In some input cases you might get extra number as last element of output

Answer (score 0):

It Work now,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Exp2
{
    class Program2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program2 pgm = new Program2();
            Console.Write("Enter number of Arrays do you want : ");
            int numberOfArrays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] narray = new int[numberOfArrays];
            int[] el=new int[100];
            int[] el1 = new int[100];
            List<int> list1 = new List<int>(100);
            List<int> list2 = new List<int>(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < narray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number of Elements do you want in Array {0}: ",i+1);
                int ai = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int j = 0; j < ai; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the {1} Elements do you want in Array {0}: ", i+1,j+1);
                    //list1[j]= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    int kj = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    list1.Add(kj);
                }
                //el1 =el1.Concat(el).ToArray();
                list2.AddRange(list1);
            }
            foreach (int val in list2)
            {
                Console.Write(val+" ");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all..!